# How can I enforce two function parameters have the same template type?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to create a registry in which I can register sensors with associated sensor processing stages.

**TLDR:** How can I enforce two function parameters have a common template parameter/member type where both inherit from abstract classes and can be placed into collections which accept any objects derived from these abstract classes?

Ideally, I would like to have something like this

```
// registry
map<string, Sensor> sensors;
map<string, SensorProcessing> processors;

// sensor base class
class Sensor
{
    virtual Data sense();
}

// processing base class
class SensorProcessing
{
    virtual void process(Data d);
}

// data kind base class
struct Data { string name; }
```

where `Sensor` and `SensorProcessing` are abstract types.
Ideally, the collection should accept any derived type of sensor or processing.

When I register the sensor and a processing stage, I would like to enforce that the `SensorProcessing` object can handle the data produced by the `Sensor` object it is registered with. 
For instance, it would not make sense to pair a processing stage operating on images with a sensor that outputs laser scans.

Something like this for the registration would be nice:

```
void register_sensor(string name, Sensor s, SensorProcessing p)
{
    // enforce that p eats what s produces, in a typesafe but polymorphic manner
    static_assert(std::is_same<s::data_type, p::data_type>);
}
```

But of course it's not that simple because with the arguments of `register_sensor()` being the base types, I can't at compile time check that they agree on the data type they use without templating. I'm not sure how to do this however, and also place sensors and processors into their own class hierarchies.

Comment: Which c++ version are you using?

Comment: Currently 11, but I'm open to suggestions with newer versions.

Comment: Well if you have the option always go to the newest standard, which is c++ 17 atm.

Comment: _Ideally, the collection should accept any derived type of sensor or processing._ Value types of maps need to be base-class pointers to employ polymorphism. Something as `map<string, std::unique_ptr<Sensor>> sensors;`. Then, you can insert a pointer to an object of any type derived from `Sensor` to such a map.

Comment: You need a [mcve] that describes what you want to achieve. Why can't you pass polymorphic arguments to register_sensor? How is the objects data type determined?

Comment: That part is actually wrong, I'll remove it from the question.

Comment: For your collection, take a look at [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). You can use it like `std::variant<std::unique_ptr<Sensor>, std::unique_ptr<SensorProcessing>>` and use that as a container element type.

Comment: The problem with your type checking in `register_sensor` is that you use runtime polymorphism to store the objects but want compile time checks. However this is not impossible if a copy of the objects should be stored (which you are doing anyway atm, because you pass by value).

Comment: @Timo Yes, that is the conundrum, I'm not sure what I want can even be done, unless I add runtime type information to my classes which I can then check. Would like the compiler to help me though.

Comment: How manu types?  Why a map?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the data type at compile time, if you create the pointer inside your function call:

```
template <typename TSensor, typename TProcessing, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Sensor, TSensor> && std::is_base_of_v<SensorProcessing, TProcessing>>>
void register_sensor(std::string const& name, TSensor s, TProcessing p)
{
    // enforce that p eats what s produces, in a typesafe but polymorphic manner
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename TSensor::data_type, typename TProcessing::data_type>, "Data type missmatch");

    // create the pointers here and move s and p in
}
```

Note that this will create a copy of the Sensor and SensorProcessing objects that you pass in.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/8NGaH4) is a possible implementation. I'm not sure what you try to achieve with the container that you described so I picked one that makes sense from my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options.

- Use [IDispatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-idispatch), or something like that if not under Windows
- Use [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) (C++ 17)
- Use COM-based interfaces and COM registration and type library to handle all this that is already done for you.
- Use serializable objects in common formats (JSON,XML).